# Private key signing with short signature

Tags: c#, .net, digital-signature

I'm searching for a way to sign a message with a private key and then have a client validate it with the public key.

The problem now is that I have severe size constrains of the length of the signature. DSA has the shortest signature (40Bytes) of the ones build into .net, but I have to stay below 20-25Bytes.

BLS seams to have reasonable short signature sizes, but I can't find any c# implementations. Security is not a high priority.

Comment: Just hash the input and append to the text?

Comment: @kelalaka Then I couldn't verify that the message was actually send by me